# Significant Lag before action alert pop up

Tags: ios

When the following is executed, there is a significant lag when access is not granted between NSLog and the alert being shown. Even though no other methods are running.

```
[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:_accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted ==YES){

        NSLog(@"Granted");

    }else{
        NSLog(@"NO TWITTER ACCESS");
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Need Twitter Access"
                                                        message:@"Please enable twitter access." 
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

Comment: You need to do UI updates on the main thread, not a background thread.

Comment: How can you tell that its on a background thread?

Comment: I'm assuming it is since it is being called from an asynchronous completion block which are typically called on some non-main thread. And the symptoms you describe are typical when doing UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rmaddy. Showing the alert on the main thread solved the lag problem.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
            [alert show];
        } );
```